# How can I pass an id of one object to the controller of another object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I know this has been asked but no solution has worked.

I'm trying to pass a group id to a procedure controller so I may make that procedure belong to that group.

Group Show View:

```
  <%= link_to 'Create a Procedure', new_procedure_path(:group => @group.id), class: 'btn btn-default btn-small' %>
```

Procedure controller:

```
  def new
    @procedure = Procedure.new
    @group = Group.find(params[:group])
```

Routes :

```
  resources :groups, only: [:new, :create, :show, :destroy]
  resources :procedures
```

Comment: You've only shown the `#new` method in your controller. Please also show the `#create` method, which is where the `Procedure` record will actually be persisted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If group_id is required, make it part of the url and won't need it in the form view.  You'll have group_id in the params: `params[:group_id]` is what the controller should expect.

```
resources :groups, only: [:new, :create, :show, :destroy] do
  resources :procedures
end
```

In your controller, do this:

```
def new
  @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
  @procedure = @group.procedures.new
end
```

And you'd link to the new page like this

```
<%= link_to 'Create a Procedure', new_group_procedure_path(@group), class: 'btn btn-default btn-small' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

To further add to `Swards` answer, you're looking at [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)...

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :groups, except: [:edit, :update] do
   resources :procedures #-> url.com/groups/:group_id/procedures/new
end
```

--

When you send a request to your server, you're requesting a "resource".

As defined by the [HTTP spec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol),

> The client submits an HTTP request message to the server. The server, which **provides resources such as HTML files** and other content, or performs other functions on behalf of the client

This is why the Rails routes have `resources` directives.

In your case, the resources you're requesting need to be dependent on another "parent" resource, hence you'd use the "nested" pattern. This provides a parameter of the "parent" var in your dependent controller:

```
#app/controllers/procedures_controller.rb
class ProceduresController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_group

   def new
      @procedure = @group.procedures.new
   end

   private

   def set_group
      @group = Group.find params[:group_id]
   end
end
```

--

Your linking method would work from `Swards` recommendation; you may also benefit from [`polymorphic_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html):

```
<%= link_to 'Create a Procedure', new_polymorphic_path([@group, :procedure]), class: 'btn btn-default btn-small' %>
```

Comment: So the solution worked but now when I'm trying to submit my form I get a No route matches [POST] "/groups/14/procedures/new". Not sure why this is because shouldn't resources automatically create a post route?

Comment: It's because you're passing a `POST` request to your `new` action, it should be `GET`